# C# multiple if statements - object-oriented programming

Tags: c#, oop

I am new to object oriented programming and C# in general.

I created some logic with If statements, however I am not sure how to structure it, so that it prints the logic only if the boolean is true.

Here is my code:

```
public class Log : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string message;
    public bool toPrint;
    public int score;
    public int score2;

    void Start()
    {
        if (toPrint == true )
        {
            Debug.Log(message);
        }

        else if (score > score2)
        {
            Debug.Log("Score is bigger than Score2");
        }

        else if (score2 > score)
        {
            Debug.Log("Score2 is bigger than Score");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("They are equal!");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: "Object-oriented" - not "orientated" ...

Comment: sorry, corrected it. @marc_s

Comment: And what exactly is ypur question? Dou you get any error? Or does your program give you unexoected results?

Comment: No errors, but my structure was incorrect, as it compared them even tho the boolean was set to false. @HimBromBeere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose all the statements that you want to exectue when `toPrint` is `true` in an if statement:

```
void Start()
{
    if (toPrint)
    {
        Debug.Log(message);

        if (score > score2)
        {
            Debug.Log("Score is bigger than Score2");
        }
        else if (score2 > score)
        {
            Debug.Log("Score2 is bigger than Score");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("They are equal!");
        }
    }
}
```

The if-statements are nested now, instead of chained. The decisions whether we should print and which message we want to print are separated now.

Note that you don't have to test with `toPrint == true`, since all the if-statement needs, is a Boolean. `toPrint` is already a Boolean containing the correct value. Comparing it to `true` yields `true` when `toPrint` is `true` and `false` when `toPrint` is `false`. The `== true` doesn't change anything, just as `x * 1` is the same as simply `x`.

Comment: that's exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the structure you are looking for, though its hard to understand what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Just make sure your variables are initialized with values.

```
public class Log : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string message;
    public bool toPrint;
    public int score;
    public int score2;

    void Start()
    {
        if (score > score2)
        {
            message = "Score is bigger than Score2";
        }
        else if (score2 > score)
        {
            message = "Score2 is bigger than Score";
        }
        else
        {
            message = "They are equal!";
        }
        if (toPrint == true)
        {
            Debug.Log(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to have a print method:

```
void Print(string message)
{
    if (!toPrint)
    {
        return;
    }

    Debug.Log(message);
}
```

Now, the rest of the code does not have to concern itself with `toPrint`:

```
public class Log : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string message;
    public bool toPrint;
    public int score;
    public int score2;

    void Start()
    {
        // Print(message);
        if (score > score2)
        {
            Print("Score is bigger than Score2");
        }
        else if (score2 > score)
        {
            Print("Score2 is bigger than Score");
        }
        else
        {
            Print("They are equal!");
        }
    }

    void Print(string text)
    {
        if (!toPrint)
        {
            return;
        }

        Debug.Log(text);
    }
}
```